# Swift And Spritekit sceneDidLoad being called more than one

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, scene

I'm working with a simple game , I have MenuScene : the user can choose the type of the game and GamePlayScene .

First time user choose game type every thing is good , but the second time all methods called twice , and the third time methods called three time etc .

I try to use didMoveToView but still have the same problem.

should I delete the scene after finish the game ? if yes how?.

this is how I transition between scenes .

```
extension SKScene {
    func presentSceneWith(NameOfScene scene : String){
        if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: scene){
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            self.view?.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }
}
```

I use it for present to GamePlayScene and back to MenuScene.

Comment: Can you show us the code you use to transition between scenes?

Comment: edit the question @ThrowingSpoon

Comment: Whatever is calling presentSceneWith is calling it on every iteration of SKScene you build.  The old Scene is never getting destroyed and is floating in memory somewhere.  Find the thing that is holding onto the old scenes, kill it, and you should see the problem go away.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon so should I remove the scene after finish the game ? like removeFromParent()

Comment: no, presenting the new scene is suppose to free the old scene,  Some @$$hole in your code is holding it hostage, hire a sniper and take him out LoL

Comment: I got it , thanks my sniper is ready to search :D

Comment: look up "retain cycle" and learn about it.  it will give you a better understanding of why your code is doing what it is doing right now.

Comment: @knight0fDragon sure thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First : I'm using **Firebase Database** .

So the problem is : I was using **If Statement** inside the observe .

like :

```
private func searchForOpponents(){
   let ref = Database.database().reference()
   ref.child("activePlayers").child("waiting").observe( DataEventType.value) { (snapshot) in
   // the problem when I put if statement like this
   if snapshot == something {
      presentToNextScene()
   }
}
```

**ref.observe** called more than one in the second so basically I was present to next scene more than one time .

**The solution** : in my case I use **ref.observeSingelEvent()** and change the **DataEventType** to **childChange .**